# Hotspot says no internet , after update my motog plus to orieo

Tags: android, motorola

I have update my motog5 plus to android 8 , after that onwards my phone hotspot is not providing Internet to connected device . I searched lot could not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

**motog5 plus settings ->Network and internet ->menu in top right ->reset wifi ... ->Reset**  Now forget that existing connection with other device then connect again its start working